# How are RSU's vesting on the weekend priced for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, rsu

My current understanding of how RSU's work is that they are taxed as regular income based on the price of the stock on the day of vesting.

However, if RSU's vest on a Saturday, are there SEC or IRS regulations that say what the price is for tax purposes?

For example, if the last closing price of a stock was $50 on the Friday before, and started trading at $40 on the following Monday, are the RSU's taxed as $50 of income per share, or $40, or something else entirely?